# Tried to delete symbolic link on WSL from Explorer, now cannot delete

Tags: windows-explorer, symbolic-link, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to delete a symbolic link from /usr/local/bin from Explorer (I'm using WSL), and now I can't delete it at all. When I try to delete it from CMD or Bash, it says "Permission denied." When I try to change anything related to permissions on the file, it also says "permission denied" or something around that line. I cannot remove /usr/local/bin, and I cannot create a new text file to replace this file. The file is also a dangling link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
 chkdsk /r
```

as administrator in Command Prompt deleted the link.